# Loading Tab Reader Parameter into ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, mapinfo, symbology

In our office, we have a large set of MapInfo TAB files, and are planning to migrate those data to ArcGIS Geodatabase with the same symbology available in the TAB file.

On a individual TAB file to GDB, we can do it like:

- Import data from TAB A to GDB A using Data Interoperability, by its corresponding CRS.
- Then adding GDB A's featureclass to ArcMap and "load symbology from TAB file" using TAB Reader though unique data
- Then save applied symbology to ".lyr" file or converting them to "Representation".

The following figure explain the workflow, not the ModelBuilder.

[image]

To convert hundreds of TAB files is taking a lot of time. So, I thought of doing with coding or ModelBuilder. Since I am very poor with Python or any other coding, I am going with ModelBuilder. The problem arises when I tried to load symbology from TAB file.

Could any one help me out in this regard?

Comment: If this is to progress I think we need more detailed steps to be provided.  If you tell us precisely what tools, and what parameter values you are using to get to where you are stuck, then you may be able to attract an expert to volunteer to help you.